# Integral of the exponential integral function

Tags: integration

I have an integral of the form:
$$\int_{-a}^{a} E_1(ax^2)dx$$
I appreciate if somebody give me an analytical solution for the above integral.
Thank you!

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%5BEi(x%5E4),x%5D

Comment: It has singularity at zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question was asked about 5 years ago, but it is never too late if the outcome is good!

Firstly, see that
$$
E_1(ax^2) = \int_{ax^2}^\infty \frac{e^{-u}\mathrm{d}u}{u} = \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-atx^2}\mathrm{d}t}{t},
$$
whose first derivative with respect to $x$ is
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} E_1(ax^2)}{\mathrm{d}x} = \int_1^\infty \frac{\partial e^{-atx^2}}{\partial x} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t} = -2ax \int_1^\infty e^{-atx^2} \mathrm{d}t = -2ax \frac{e^{-ax^2}}{ax^2} = -\frac{2e^{-ax^2}}{x}.
$$

If we could cancel out $x$ in the denominator and integrate the result with respect to $x$, we would have a function proportional to the error function $\mathrm{erf}(\sqrt{a}x)$. Notice that
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} \left(xE_1(ax^2)\right)}{\mathrm{d}x} = E_1(ax^2) + x\frac{\mathrm{d}E_1(ax^2)}{\mathrm{d}x} = E_1(ax^2) -2e^{-ax^2}.
$$

We can get rid of the undesired second term with the error function. Check that
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\,\mathrm{erf}(\sqrt{a}x)}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \frac{\mathrm{d} \phantom{x}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_0^{\sqrt{a}x} e^{-t^2}\mathrm{d}t = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-ax^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}(\sqrt{a}x)}{\mathrm{d}x} = 2\sqrt{\frac{a}{\pi}}e^{-ax^2}.
$$

Thus, we have that
$$
\int E_1(ax^2)\mathrm{d}x = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\mathrm{erf}(\sqrt{a}x) + xE_1(ax^2) + C.
$$

In particular, for the given bounds,
$$
\int_{-a}^a E_1(ax^2)\mathrm{d}x = 2\left[\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\mathrm{erf}(a^{3/2}) + aE_1(a^3)\right].
$$